# Printing results from PDF box output to a text file

Tags: java, pdf, text, pdfbox

I am working on a class which Parses a PDF document with PDF Box, its purpose is to create a text file (its name is `PdfTestFile.txt`) with the results. We have gotten it to print the parsed text to the console, but I don't know how to make it write the results to the `.txt` file that the class creates (name is `PdfTestFile.txt`).

I tried to use `out.print(Text);` but it gives me an error saying that:

> out cannot be resolved

The class `PdfEasyManager` calls the class `EasySearch` in which we see the error mentioned above.

Below is the code that I have where the String Text is what I would like to print to the file `PdfTestFile.txt`:

Class " PdfEasyManager":

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    public class PdfEasyManager {

    static BufferedWriter writer; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Evergreen.txt")); 

        EasySearch easysearch = new EasySearch();
       // pdfManager.setFilePath("PDFextTEST.pdf");
        System.out.println(easysearch.ToText());      
        //out.println(easysearch.ToText()); 
     }
    }
```

Class "EasySearch" :

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class EasySearch {

       private PDFParser parser;
       private PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;
       private PDDocument pdDoc ;
       private COSDocument cosDoc ;

       private String Text ;
       private String filePath;

       private File file;
       static BufferedWriter writer; 
       //writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(BLnumber +         (date.toString().substring(4, 10))+ ".org"));

        public EasySearch() {

        }
      //public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{


       public String ToText() throws IOException



       {
           this.pdfStripper = null;
           this.pdDoc = null;
           this.cosDoc = null;

           writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("PdfTestFile.txt"));
           file = new File("C:/Users/Jon Smith/Desktop/Sample.pdf");
           parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));

           parser.parse();
           cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
           pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
           pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
           pdDoc.getNumberOfPages();

           pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);// reading text from page 1
              // pdfStripper.setEndPage(10);// to 10    
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());// if you want to get text from full pdf file use this code



           Text = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
           out.print(Text); //this is the line that gives me the error
           return Text;


       }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `out` which is not present in your class. Use `System.out.print(Text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but

> writer.write(Text);

solves the issue I was having